# how to handle long names on UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, itunes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing font size of tabbaritem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576592/changing-font-size-of-tabbaritem)

I have three tabs in UITabBar. The titles I have to set are very long so the titles are getting overlapped. Is there any way to fit those titles in a corresponding tab like by increasing number of lines. Or is it not possible to write long titles in UITabBar without overlapping.

Comment: have you find nay solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just a unique solution ......

Set the image in Tabbar with the name rather than setting the names.

So,even that would not make the Tabbar text to be overlapping each other.