# How to increase the size of UITabBarItem in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbaritem

I want to increase the Text size of UITabBarItem in my application.It is not visible clearly with its default color and size.

I tried this code but give me error -->***UITabBar for instant message does not declare method with selector 'setTitleTextAttributes'.***

Does any know how to do it?

```
[yourTabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [UIColor whiteColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, 
    [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0,0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, 
    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the default size is fully conveninet for the user. Anyway you want, maybe you should make your own `<Tabbar>` with `UIView`, `UIButtons` and `UITabbar`-style images.

Answer (score 0):

`setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` is only available in iOS 5.0 or later. Please refer to [UIBarItem Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarItem/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:) (`UITabBarItem` is subclass of `UIBarItem`). For prior versions of iOS, I think you'd better create your own customized tab bar.

And you may also want to try other methods from the answers in [Changing font size of tabbaritem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576592/changing-font-size-of-tabbaritem).

Answer (score 0):

For that you should create dynamic tab bar using UITabbar class.

.Using this You can allow own size text ,image,color.