# How to change the font size of the tab bar controller item name?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am doing an app based on tabbarController. I have a 3 tabbar items.

My question is: How can I change the font-style for the title on the tab-bar item?

Comment: Trust me none of the user reads the text, I prefer rather spending time on a really good descriptive icon

Comment: yes. i want it through programatically

Comment: can you explain your question? when do you want to change the name of you tabbar item? is there any action that will invoke a method to change the name of that tab bar? and also what have you tried?

Comment: like when i run the app, all the tab bar items will come rite ? at that time all my images with titles should come..

Comment: @doNotCheckMyBlog - I strongly disagree. Icons are useful *once a reader knows what the choice means*, because they are easier to see at a glance.  The *FIRST* time a reader sees choices, text is clearer. In my experience, most icons could mean any of a number of possible things, which the text clarifies. Also consider that there are a wide range of users: some are like you and prefer icons, others are like me: I would prefer to ALWAYS have (a tiny, short) text with EVERY icon, except for widely standardized icons.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                            [UIColor grayColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                            nil]];
```

Comment: it's not coming.. it's showing warning and terminating from there

Comment: Why is this upvoted 7 times when there's no such method for UITabBarItem?

Comment: For anyone still having issues with this: the method as typed above is incorrect. You need to add the `forState:` parameter after `setTitleTextAttributes:`. It will then compile without warnings and work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

This will change ur UITabBarItem fonts once and for all throughout the app

For Swift use this in AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching:

Swift 3:

```
UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Montserrat", size: 11)!], for: .normal)

UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.red,NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Montserrat", size: 11)!], for: .selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I dont think there's a way to do this. If you're desperate, you'll need to write your own tab bar.

Comment: Why is this upvoted?  There are solutions proposed for this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2576592/199364  .  Or are you saying that the question here is different?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Absolutely correct. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this isn't possible currently on iOS unless you build your own custom tab bar, which isn't very difficult with storyboarding on iOS5.

Comment: Sorry, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible ,create custome tab bar subclassing UITabbar

Comment: Sorry, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this error: `'UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - Use NSShadowAttributeName with an NSShadow instance as the value.`,try this.

```
NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
shadow.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor];
shadow.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.5);

NSDictionary *attribute = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
[UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:10.0f], NSFontAttributeName,
[UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
 shadow,NSShadowAttributeName,nil];
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attribute forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
[[UITabBarItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITabBar class], nil]
  setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:
    [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:130/255.0f blue:202/255.0f alpha:1.0],
    NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Signika-Semibold" size:20.0]
  }
forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Care to clarify what it does exactly?