# Increasing the font size of UITabBarItem text

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBarController with 4 tab bar items in it. I do not have any image to put over there. I wanted the text to look bigger and span in two lines if possible to compensate for image. It looks little odd now.

Any clue how to achieve this.

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576592/changing-font-size-of-tabbaritem

Comment: Tries this but did not get much help... I am not finding the place where to put that piece of code. There is no such delegate exposed by UITabBArController where I could put the suggested code and in the viewWillAppear of my view controller its not working out.