# Tabbar item appearance in ios 4.3

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4.5

I have a UITabbar and I m customizing  its appearance which works fine in ios >5 .But when I run the same one in iphone 4.3 simulator it crashes because of tabbar appearance.

```
 for(UIViewController *tab in  tabBarController1.viewControllers)

        {
            [tab.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                    [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
                                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
```

How can I get the same appearance in iphone 4.3 simulator also ?

Any help would be appreciable...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576592/changing-font-size-of-tabbaritem

Comment: setTitleTextAttributes is not availabel in ios 4.3, that's why it crashes.You have to right ur own tababrcontroller

Comment: @AmanAggarwal when writing my own tabbarcontroller I m writing it in appdelegate .Can u tell how can I write my own tabbarcontroller ?

Comment: check out this http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar&commit=Search

Answer (score 0):

@Aman Aggarwal gave the answer

The apple documentation says

> setTitleTextAttributes:forState: Sets the title’s text attributes for a given control state.
>   ...
>   Availability **Available in iOS 5.0 and later.**

Only available in iOS 5.0 and later

Comment: Ok I found it is available in ios 5 or later.But there may be some alternative to achieve the same appearance but diferent attributes in 4.3.i want to know that?

Comment: You will find workarounds for that I think, but if you need to publish on the app store I am note sure it will pass the submission process.

Answer (score 0):

It needs a tricky implementation. Here is one. You can add buttons over the tab bar in your application. Its tricky but it works.

For this you have to subclass the `UITabBarController`.

Something like this

**BaseViewController.h**

```
@interface BaseViewController : UITabBarController
{
}

// Create custom UIButtons and add it to the tab bar
-(void) addButtons;

@end
```

**BaseViewController.m**

```
#import "BaseViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation BaseViewController
// Create custom UIButtons and add it to the tab bar

-(void) addButtons
{
    UIImageView *backgroundImage    =   [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(20, 0, 330, 60)];
    [backgroundImage setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"bottom.png"]];
    [backgroundImage setCenter: self.tabBar.center];
    [self.view addSubview: backgroundImage];
    [backgroundImage release];

    UIButton    *firstTabbarButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    firstTabbarButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 52.0, 68, 49);
    [firstTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"home_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [firstTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"home_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [firstTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"home.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [firstTabbarButton addTarget: self action: @selector(goButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [firstTabbarButton setCenter: CGPointMake(33, self.tabBar.center.y)];
    [firstTabbarButton setTag: 1000];
    [firstTabbarButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted: NO];
    [self.view addSubview: firstTabbarButton];

    UIButton    *secondTabbarButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    secondTabbarButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 52.0, 68, 49);
    [secondTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"lab_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [secondTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"lab_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [secondTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"lab_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [secondTabbarButton addTarget: self action: @selector(goButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [secondTabbarButton setCenter: CGPointMake(96, self.tabBar.center.y)];
    [secondTabbarButton setTag: 1001];
    [secondTabbarButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted: NO];
    [self.view addSubview: secondTabbarButton];

    UIButton    *thirdTabbarButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    thirdTabbarButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 52.0, 68, 49);
    [thirdTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"others.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [thirdTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"others.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [thirdTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"others_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [thirdTabbarButton addTarget: self action: @selector(goButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [thirdTabbarButton setCenter: CGPointMake(287, self.tabBar.center.y)];
    [thirdTabbarButton setTag: 1004];
    [thirdTabbarButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted: NO];
    [self.view addSubview: thirdTabbarButton];

    UIButton    *forthTabbarButton  =   [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    forthTabbarButton.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 52.0, 68, 49);
    [forthTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"history_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [forthTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"history_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [forthTabbarButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"history.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [forthTabbarButton addTarget: self action: @selector(goButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [forthTabbarButton setCenter: CGPointMake(223, self.tabBar.center.y)];
    [forthTabbarButton setAdjustsImageWhenHighlighted: NO];
    [forthTabbarButton setTag: 1003];
    [self.view addSubview: forthTabbarButton];

    UIImage *centerImage  =   [UIImage imageNamed:@"go_btn.png"];
    UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 52.0, 62, 62);
    [button setTag: 1002];
    [button setBackgroundImage:centerImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [button addTarget: self action: @selector(goButtonClicked:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    CGFloat heightDifference = button.frame.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;

    if (heightDifference < 0)
        button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
        CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
        center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
        button.center = center;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

@end
```

This will work. But beware about App store submission guide lines. Try this.